# How to display the result of a function I created?

Tags: c#

I need to create a function that does something. The user then inputs two numbers and I use the function and display the result. I don't know how to display it. I've been trying to google "how to call a function", "how to display the result of a function" and so on.

```
    static int SpoctiDPH(int cena, int dph)
    {
        int vysledek = cena * (dph / 100);
        return vysledek;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int cena, dph;
        int vysledek;

        cena = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        dph = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        SpoctiDPH(cena ,dph);

        Console.WriteLine(vysledek); //<- This line says use of unassigned variable and I don't know how to fix it and display the result of the function
        Console.ReadLine();<
    }
```

Comment: Wow...since your returning an int...declare an int and assign it to the function.
ie...int x=SpoctiDPH(cena,dph);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why you are confused as to why `vysledek` does not have the expected value is related to [variable scopes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elMQ5YtZPxA).

To call a method/function, you write its name and pass some parameters in the parenthesis, like this: `SpoctiDPH(cena, dph);`

In your case, this method(function) [returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement) a certain value. You, however, haven't used this returned value anywhere.

You can use that value by assigning it to some variable, for example, `int vysledek`. You can do that like this: `vysledek = SpoctiDPH(cena, dph);`

That way, variable `vysledek` is not unassigned anymore. Printing it won't result in an error anymore.

Comment: @pocketwatch please consider accepting the answer that was most helpful to you.